# How is $(XDX^{-1})^2 = XD^2X^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Lets say we have a square matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ which is diagonalisable such that $A=XDX^{-1}$. I do not understand the following step:

$$(XDX^{-1})^2 = XDX^{-1}XDX^{-1}= XD^2X^{-1}$$

I do not understand what is happening between the LHS and RHS of the second equal sign.
Can anyone explain that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$X^{-1}X = I$$ from the definition inverse. You can then scratch it in a product.

Then the $D$s meet from both sides and build $D^2$.

Comment: Oh...Now I see! Did not expect that. How could I not see this... You get the mark in eleven minutes.